# Runtime error for UVA Judge Online with C++ (Problem 10050)

Tags: c++, runtime

Hi im having a problem with my program and i honestly dont know where or how to solve it. Here is the code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool ok;
    int testcases;
    scanf("%d", &testcases);
    vector<int> days(testcases);
    vector<int> parties(testcases);
    vector<vector<int>> hartals(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < testcases; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &(days[i]));
        scanf("%d", &parties[i]);
        hartals[i].resize(parties[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < parties[i]; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &hartals[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    vector<vector<int>> initialHartalsValues = hartals;
    for (int i = 0; i < testcases; i++)
    {
        int week = 0, nonWorkingDays = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < days[i] + 1; j++)
        {
            if (j != 1 && j - 7 * (week + 1) == 1)
            {
                week++;
            }
            ok = true;
            for (int k = 0; k < hartals[i].size(); k++)
            {
                if (hartals[i][k] == j)
                {
                    hartals[i][k] = hartals[i][k] + initialHartalsValues[i][k];
                    if (ok && j - 7 * week != 6 && j - 7 * week != 7)
                    {
                        ok = false;
                        nonWorkingDays++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", nonWorkingDays);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program works fine and it does its job but when i submit it to the judges i throws a runtime error and i cant find where it is.

Comment: Thank you for not using `#include <bits/stdc++>`.  Now, if you could change your ways to not use `using namespace std;`

Comment: Often it 's worth temporarily swapping the `[]`s for calls to `at` to take advantage of `at`'s bounds checking.

Comment: Also a good idea to add a brief summary of what the program is supposed to do to the question.

Comment: Unrelated: Looks like you only use `parties` to size the inner `vector` of `hartals`. You can probably just use a tighter-scoped `int` here and save some dynamic allocations.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks everyone for your replies and your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
 vector<vector<int>> hartals(2);`
```

Constructs two entries in the outer `vector` and no entries in the inner `vector`s`.

But then we have

```
for (int i = 0; i < testcases; i++)
{
    ...
    hartals[i].resize(parties[i]);
```

`testcases` probably isn't 2, so `i` can easily be out of bounds and invoke the dreaded [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). On your machine the program manifests behaviour that appears to "work". On the judging system, you have better luck and the program crashes. Strange as it sounds, crashes are good luck. With a crash you know you have a bug.

Give

```
vector<vector<int>> hartals(testcases);
```

a test and see if it helps out.  Could be more bugs in there, but that's probably the one you're tripping over right now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for the help. That was causing the runtime error.